# ZTE phone home screen blinks off and on

Tags: troubleshooting

My phone screen has task manager and a clear all button at the bottom. When I try to push phone or an app, it keeps disappearing and comes back on. I can't use any apps and I can't talk or text because every time anything is touched or even if nothing is touched the phone screen blinks on and off with apps and no apps, apps and no apps, repeatedly. I can't use the phone, because the home screen keeps flashing off and on. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: @necolesager Welcome to Android Enthusiasts Q&A. It would help to troubleshoot your phone if you could post a comment or edit your question and provide the model of your ZTE phone.

Comment: If you expect someone to help you, you shouldn't make it that hard to understand your issue. Sorry if I might sound mean, but all I can see in your post looks like gibberish – as if there was an explosion in the press and the letters landed on this page.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check under [Developer options](https://www.androidcentral.com/all-about-your-phones-developer-options) if there is an option to make the screen flash with heavy app usage.
2. Look in your installed apps to see if you have installed any shady apps recently and uninstall them. In particular search for apps or themes that have permission to wake up the phone.